# How can I achieve this use case diagram using tikzpicture environment

Tags: positioning, tikz-uml

I am using the [last example of the Chapter 3 - "Use case diagrams" TikZ-UML manual (pp. 34-35)](https://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/var/files/doc/tikzumlmanual.pdf).

Please consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{pgf}{Your graphic driver}        % FOR DELETE WARNING OF 'Package pgf Warning: Your graphic driver...'. From https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63522/152550

\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\tikzumlset{fill usecase=white}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{umlsystem}[x=6] {Name of the system}
            \umlusecase[name=a,width=2.5cm] {Use case a}
            \umlusecase[name=b,x=6,width=2.5cm] {Use case b}
            \umlusecase[name=c,x=6,y=-3,width=2.5cm] {Use case c}
            \umlusecase[name=d,y=-3,width=2.5cm] {Use case d}
        \end{umlsystem}

        \umlactor[y=-1] {Actor 1}
        \umlactor[y=-3] {Actor 2}
        \umlactor[x=18] {Actor 3}

        \umlassoc{Actor 1}{a}
        \umlassoc{Actor 2}{a}

        \umlextend{a}{b}
        \umlinclude{c}{d}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image: What I have]

If possible, I want to implement three changes:

1. **Put `Name of the system` label outside the rectangle (above it).**
2. **Put `≪extend≫` and `≪include≫` labels above its lines.**
3. **Bend down (or up) the association between `Actor 3` and `Use case 1` (insted of `\umlassoc{Actor 3}{a}` because it overlaps with `\umlextend{a}{b}`).**

I want this:

[image: What I want]

From what I have seen, the manual says nothing about it.

*([@N. Kielbasiewicz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/100441/n-kielbasiewicz) please read this question!)*

Thanks!!

Comment: You will need to use normal TikZ commands.  The problem is figuring out what tikz-uml is actually doing (especially the node names).  Remember that everything tikz-uml does can be done using TikZ, albeit with more work.

Comment: Just to support what @JohnKormylo is saying: I had a quick look at the internals of that style file and am not surprised that you find it hard to adjust things to become as you like them to be. Among other things, it does nest `tikzpicture`s when creating the actors. That means that when you start customizing things, there is great chance things go uncontrollable. If I was you, I'd just copy the actor code, define a `pic` using it, and then do an ordinary `tikzpicture`.

Comment: @marmot do you confirm that it is currently impossible to make those changes only with `tikz-uml` loaded? I am planning to contact `tikz-uml`'s creator.

Comment: @marmot I found `\newcommand{\umlextend}[3][]` in line 2810 of the `tikz-uml.sty` file. I do not see how to move the `extend` label above of the relation (anyway you neither).

Comment: @JohnKormylo thank you, it is very useful! Do you know how to mix `tikz-uml` commands with normal `tikz`?

Comment: @manooooh No, I do not think it is impossible to do these changes with `tikz-uml`. What I am saying is that you may run into problems that cannot be resolved. If you contact the creator, you may suggest to replace the actor by a `pic` with a local bounding box instead of a `tizpicture` in a node.

Comment: .The eaisest solution would be to put the entire tikz-uml picture into a savebox, then put the savebox into a tikz node. Using [remember picture] you can even preserve the tikz-uml node names (if you know them).

Comment: @JohnKormylo which part of the MWE is the `tikz-uml` picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by John Kormylo, you can do this by mixing in normal TikZ drawing commands.

1. For the name of the system, set the title of the `umlsystem` empty, and immediately after `\end{umlsystem}` add

   ```
   \node [above] at (current bounding box.north) {Name of the system};
   ```
2. While one could redefine the `\umlrelation` macro to place the "stereo" next to the lines, it might be just as easy to just draw them manually with

   ```
   \draw [tikzuml dependency style] (a) -- node[above] {$\ll \text{extend} \gg$} (b);
   \draw [tikzuml dependency style] (d) -- node[above] {$\ll \text{include} \gg$} (c);
   ```

   The coordinates corresponds to the name you've given your four `\umlusecase`s (with `name=a` etc.).
3. The actors are placed in nodes with the name you give the actors, so the bent association between `a` and `Actor 3` can be drawn with

   ```
   \draw [tikzuml association style] (a) to[bend right=10] (Actor 3);
   ```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\tikzumlset{fill usecase=white}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{umlsystem}[x=6] {} % empty title
            \umlusecase[name=a,width=2.5cm] {Use case a}
            \umlusecase[name=b,x=6,width=2.5cm] {Use case b}
            \umlusecase[name=c,x=6,y=-3,width=2.5cm] {Use case c}
            \umlusecase[name=d,y=-3,width=2.5cm] {Use case d}
        \end{umlsystem}
        \node [above] at (current bounding box.north) {Name of the system};

        \umlactor[y=-1] {Actor 1}
        \umlactor[y=-3] {Actor 2}
        \umlactor[x=18] {Actor 3}

        \umlassoc{Actor 1}{a}
        \umlassoc{Actor 2}{a}


        % \umlextend{a}{b}
        % \umlinclude{c}{d}

        % manual versions of the above
        \draw [tikzuml dependency style] (a) -- node[above] {$\ll \text{extend} \gg$} (b);
        \draw [tikzuml dependency style] (d) -- node[above] {$\ll \text{include} \gg$} (c);

        % bent association
        \draw [tikzuml association style] (a) to[bend right=10] (Actor 3);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent explanation! Just what I wanted. I only change `$\ll \text{extend/include} \gg$` to `$\ll \! \text{extend/include} \! \gg$` to get approximately the same space as the original. Many thanks! P.S. You could use [your prev answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462677/152550) to get rid of every `width=2.5cm` `;)` haha.